# Create A PDF File From Java Base64 String In Objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, web-services, pdf

I catch a string from web service response as java base64 and want to save into a file as a PDF in objective c And Show that PDF file in Web View in Xcode

Comment: OK.  Start by writing some code.  When you get stuck, come back with a question.

Comment: NSString *decodeString = @"JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9EZWNvZGVQYXJtczw8L0NvbG9ycyAzL1ByZWRpY3RvciAxNS9CaXRzUGVyQ29tcG9uZW50IDgvQ29sdW1ucyAxOTIwPj4vVHlwZS9YT2JqZWN0L0NvbG9yU3Bh;

Comment: like this recipe a string but when it try to decode in a nsdata it will return nil with  NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:mainstring options:0]; method